# Managing CSS priority

Tags: css

I'm making a blog and I am using a free template to manage my fron-end part, but now I want to add one class called *code_block*. Every time I write an article and I want to add a

```
<p class="code_block"> some code</p>
```

and the code piece to be displayed in a similiar to how this last code is displayed here in stackoverflow.

I went to the *END* CSS file entered:

```
.code_block{
    color: #933 !important;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

didn't work, tried adding the css directly in the html, didn't work, tried adding manualy the css while in chromium web tool, didn't work what is happening ?!

source: https://github.com/martin-varbanov96/summer-2016/tree/master/Pitonia/Django/mysql_blog/blog

EDIT:
made it more specific:

.ar

```
ticle ul li p .code_block{
    color: #933 !important;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Still not working I think priority is not the problem here.

Comment: Is there already a class called "code_block" that's being used elsewhere? CSS uses inheritance, so unless it's the last thing read, it will be over written.

Comment: When expecting the styles on dev-tools are the CSS rules striked or just not there?

Comment: Looking at the code you posted on github [here:](https://github.com/martin-varbanov96/summer-2016/blob/master/Pitonia/Django/mysql_blog/blog/about_page/static/css/style.css) It looks like all the other rules are more specific than the rule you are adding

Comment: On line 325, you have rules which are more specific for the Paragraph element.

Comment: try with a more specific rule p.code_block

Comment: @Birksy89 but I am using *!important* which should have a bigger priority

Comment: @DaveM. Tried but still not working

Comment: Aren't you trying to insert something like `<pre>` or `blockquote` inside this `<p>`?

Comment: Are you sure working on the right css file? Or are you sure that css file is linked in your page?

Answer (score 0):

ID has got more priority. Remove the color from here. Or you can override.

```
#body.home .body div p {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 780px;
}
```

You can override it like this...

```
#body.home .body div p.code_block{
    color: #933;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```